# Livewire - Ajax not being fired

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Laravel Livewire component, and Ajax events are not being fired.

[image]

I have a search input file that sends a search string to my component. No Ajax events are being fired, and the results don't get updated.

Note: the pagination Livewire control also doesnt work - Laravel pagination does work, but when I use the `UsePagination` trait then pagination doesn't work. There aren't any network calls, and no Javascript errors.

Blade component:

```
<input type="text" class="min-w-full" placeholder="Search" wire:model="search" />
```

Component:

```
  public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.manage-sites', [
            'sites' => app(WebsiteRepository::class)->query()->where('organization_name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')->paginate(10),
        ])->extends('layouts.management');

    }
```

Styles are included in the base layout page:

```
<livewire:styles />
```

and the scripts are included in the body:

```
<body>
    @yield('body')

    <livewire:scripts />
    <script src="{{ url(mix('js/app.js')) }}"></script>

    @stack('scripts')

</body>
```

The component is being included through a route definition in the web.php.

```
Route::get('manage-sites', \App\Http\Livewire\ManageSites::class)
        ->name('manage.sites.index');
```

Relevant pieces of composer:

```
"php": "^7.2.5",
"blade-ui-kit/blade-ui-kit": "^0.1.1",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
"fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
"hyn/multi-tenant": "^5.6",
"laravel-frontend-presets/tall": "^1.7",
"laravel/framework": "^7.24",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
"livewire/livewire": "^2.0",
"sentry/sentry-laravel": "^1.8",
"spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.14",
"spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^8.0.0",
"spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.16"
```

Comment: Can you clarify? The ajax search input is not working when you type something?

Comment: Can you show us how you're accessing this livewire component and more content about your blade view and Livewire component?

Comment: @tonoslfx correct - the search isnt working and no network requests are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by moving the table/search/pagination out of the main blade component, into a new Livewire component and then referencing in the main blade component as below.

```
<livewire:list-sites />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling javascript with the wrong path

<strike>`<script src="{{ url(mix('js/app.js')) }}"></script>`</strike>

- `url('app.js')` will give you the full url `http://localhost/ressource.js`
- `mix('app.js')` will give you the full url with the appropriate hash `http://localhost/ressource.js?id=1964becbdd96414518cd`

Using both may give you a weird url. I recommend to uses `mix` since it will version your JS and avoid you troubles of cache in production.

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it will fix your issue though

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an action `keydown` to trigger the search.

```html
<input type="text" class="min-w-full" placeholder="Search" 
wire:model="keyword" 
wire:keydown.debounce.350ms="search" />

// wire:keydown.debounce.350ms delays by 350ms
```

In your Livewire Search Controller

```php
public function search() {

 // $this->keyword;
 // your eloquent search query

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `wire:keydown` . The attribute `wire:model="search"` should be enough. At least I never used `wire:keydown`

Comment: How do you detect the input changes to trigger the search if not with `keydown` ?

Comment: Livewire adds a listener and trigger an ajax request on each input changes, You can modify this behavior with extra parameters `wire:model.lazy` `wire:model.defer` `wire:model.debounce.500ms` and the content of `$search` will be updated [more info](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-nested-data)

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier i added clarification... its being loaded through the web.php (Eg not through the normal <livewire:component>. Perhaps thats the issue?